# Brakeman generating exceptions on an empty file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-2.2, brakeman

After upgrading recently to `brakeman 3.3.5` I am getting a similar exception on two files. One is `app/helpers/profile_mailer` and the exception is

```
golf_mentor/app/helpers/profile_helper.rb:1 :: parse error on value ":" (tCOLON)
```

If I delete everything but the surrounding block, so the file becomes

```
module ProfilesHelper

end
```

I still get the same exception.  If I delete everything in the file, I get the following exception:

```
undefined method `force_encoding' for nil:NilClass While processing app/helpers/profiles_helper.rb
```

Looking on stackoverflow, such an error is not reported for brakeman, but it appears to be reported for a number of other apps and is related to `ruby 2.2` (I am running `2.2.1`).

The file permissions for this file are

```
-rw-r--r--  1 Chris  staff     4 16 Aug 19:57 profiles_helper.rb
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: I can't reproduce either issue. Please run Brakeman with `-d` and share the full stack traces related to the exceptions.

Comment: The full stack trace is here: https://github.com/obromios/stack_overflow_queries/blob/master/brakeman_output.txt

Comment: Thank you, but the relevant information is actually before the report and is output to stderr. Something like `brakeman -d &> out.txt`. In any case, this is bound to be a RubyParser issue, probably lack of support for some syntax. What is confusing is the empty file case.